# Bootstrap icons disappear in small devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-icons

I have the next structure, there are 3 href where i included 3 bootstrap icons, the problem is that in extra small devices the 3 icons disappear.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 text-center">
         <h4>CONTACTANOS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 text-center">
        <a class="link-light" href="#" style="text-decoration:none ; margin: .5rem;">449 388 
         09 98<i style="margin: .5rem;" class=" fs-5 bi bi-telephone"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 text-center">
        <a class="link-light" href="#" style="text-decoration:none ; margin: .5rem;">Onfiber<i
                    style="margin: .5rem;" class=" fs-5 bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 text-center">
        <a class="link-light " href="#" style="text-decoration:none ; margin: .5rem;">449 327 51 35<i style="margin: .5rem;" class="fs-5 bi bi-whatsapp"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try with the svg, rather than the icon font.  
with the svg, I got it to work in 2 code environments. 
see https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/telephone-fill/, bottom right, copy and paste the svg section.  Does it work?

Comment: Thank you, it´s perfectly working : )

Comment: glad to hear it.